# Не получается изменить цвет у бургер-меню jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно при клике изменить цвет фона у бургер меню. Добавлением класса не получается сделать. Вот так создается бургер:

```
.menu-btn span,
.menu-btn span::before,
.menu-btn span::after {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -1px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -10px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 2px;
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

Класс для изменения цвтета:

```
.toggle-black{
background-color:  #000 !important;
}
```

Код jqeury:

```
 $('.menu-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu-btn span').toggleClass('toggle-black');
})
```

Не получается таким образом цвет изменить

Comment: Приведите [mcve]. Скопировал ваш кусочек кода в сниппет, какой то цвет там вполне себе меняется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то делаете видать не так. У меня работает, правда я высоту span задал. ИМХО У вас очень странная html разметка

```js
$('.menu-btn').click(function () {
    $('.menu-btn span').toggleClass('toggle-black');
})
```

```css
.menu-btn{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.menu-btn span,
.menu-btn span::before,
.menu-btn span::after {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -1px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -10px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     display: block;
     
     background-color: #fff;
}
.toggle-black{
background-color:  #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="menu-btn"><span>Кнопка</span></button>
```